# new to lxml - selected by xpath giving too many results

Tags: python, lxml

The issue I am facing is in the code below and is probably pretty common.

Basically I want to selected xpath from a subnode on a page but it is giving me all xpath matches on the entire page.

what gives?

```
import lxml.html

def readHTML(arg):
    ret = ""
    ret = lxml.html.parse(arg)
    return ret

soup = (readHTML("http://www.myScrapingSite.com/"))

subGroup =  soup.xpath("//div[@class='colmask']")[0]

#i want this to only be the cities in subGroup but its 
#giving me the cities on the entire page..what am I doing wrong?
cities = subGroup.xpath('//li/a')
urls = {}

#so basically I am building a dictionary that is a superset of the desired set
for city in cities:
    print city.attrib['href']
    urls[city.attrib['href']] = 1

for url in urls:
    subGroup2 = readHTML(url)
```

Comment: Don't give us the URL you're scraping - just include some stripped down example HTML that triggers the problem would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `//` means relative to document root, even for subgroups. What you really want is probably  `.//` which is relative to the current node

```
cities = subGroup.xpath('.//li/a')
```

Here's an example

```
>> xmlString = '<root><taga name="a"><tagb name="first"/></taga><taga name="b"><tagb name="second"/></taga></root>'
>> xml = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlString)
>> taga = x.xpath('//taga[@name="a"]')[0]
>> taga[0].xpath('//tagb')
[<Element tagb at 7fddaa625310>, <Element tagb at 7fddaa6252b8>]
>> taga[0].xpath('.//tagb')
[<Element tagb at 7fddaa625310>]
```

You can see that `//` returns both `tagb` entries, while `.//` returns only the one inside the current node.

Comment: More likely `.//li/a`.